# combining log4j log lines

Tags: linux, logging, sed, hive, log4j

I am dealing with some hive logs created with log4j on linux. The regex used is

```
(%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t]: %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n)
```

.  I realise some lines are broken down into several lines. for example

```
2017-02-10 10:03:29,933 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(185)) - Parsing command: 

create table my_table

(std_id STRING, std_number STRING)

2017-02-10 10:03:31,296 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(209)) - Parse Completed
```

Is there a command in linux which I can use to combine the broken lines to give an output like this ;

```
2017-02-10 10:03:29,933 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(185)) - Parsing command: create table my_table (std_id STRING, std_number STRING)

2017-02-10 10:03:31,296 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(209)) - Parse Completed
```

Comment: If you edit the file in vi (I think you need to use Using `vi -b <your file>` to display carriage returns), and use `:set list` to display newlines, you seeing any pattern for when one or the other is used?  If so, you can use sed to delete the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work.

```
<myfile.log sed -nr \
-e '/^.{4}-.{2}-.{2} .{2}:.{2}:.{2},.{3} [A-Z]+ /{x;1!{s/\n/ /g;p};${g;p};d}' \
-e 'H' \
-e '${g;s/\n/ /g;p}'
```

---

**Explanation**

Let `/^.{4}-.{2}-.{2} .{2}:.{2}:.{2},.{3} [A-Z]+`  be the pattern that indicates a new log record, e.g. `2017-03-17 03:20:19,372 WARN`

**1st `-e`**

When the current row indicates a new log record

- `x`: Exchange the contents of the pattern space (which hold the current row) and the hold space.
- `1!{s/\n/ /g;p}`: If this is not the first row of the file, (within the pattern space) replace the new lines with spaces and print it
- `${g;p}` If this was the last row of the file, get it from the hold space and print it
- `d`: Delete the pattern space and start a new cycle (ignoring following commands)

**2nd `-e`**

- 'H': append the pattern space to the hold space (only when not a new log record)

**3rd `-e`**

If this was the last row of the file (`$`) and not a new log record

- `g`: Overwrite the pattern space with the content of the hold space
- `s/\n/ /g;p`: replace the new lines with spaces and print it

---

#### Demo

```
$ cat>myfile.log
2017-02-10 10:03:27,374 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(463)) - Semantic Analysis Completed
2017-02-10 10:03:29,933 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(185)) - Parsing command:

create table my_table

(std_id STRING, std_number STRING)

2017-02-10 10:03:31,296 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(209)) - Parse Completed
2017-03-17 03:04:09,297 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(927)) - OK
2017-03-17 03:20:19,372 WARN  [Driver]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(451)) - Child process exited with code 1.
2017-03-17 03:03:55,282 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(936)) - FAILED: ParseException line 1:14 cannot recognize input near 'valeus' '(' '1' in statement
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 1:14 cannot recognize input near 'valeus' '(' '1' in statement
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:204)
```

---

```
$ <myfile.log sed -nr -e '/^.{4}-.{2}-.{2} .{2}:.{2}:.{2},.{3} [A-Z]+ /{x;1!{s/\n/ /g;p};${g;p};d}' -e 'H' -e '${g;s/\n/ /g;p}'
2017-02-10 10:03:27,374 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(463)) - Semantic Analysis Completed
2017-02-10 10:03:29,933 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(185)) - Parsing command:   create table my_table  (std_id STRING, std_number STRING)
2017-02-10 10:03:31,296 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(209)) - Parse Completed
2017-03-17 03:04:09,297 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(927)) - OK
2017-03-17 03:20:19,372 WARN  [Driver]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(451)) - Child process exited with code 1.
2017-03-17 03:03:55,282 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(936)) - FAILED: ParseException line 1:14 cannot recognize input near 'valeus' '(' '1' in statement org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 1:14 cannot recognize input near 'valeus' '(' '1' in statement        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:204)
```

Comment: this is very useful. Exactly what I was looking for. Please put in the explanation when you have the time. Thanks a lot

Comment: P.s. I think this is a classic question for one of the linux/unix exchanges: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ , http://askubuntu.com/  , https://superuser.com/